# How to get Credit Memos items for an order

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get all refund items of an order only. I am using below code for this:

```
$order_id = "100001451";

$creditMemos = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection');
$creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $order_id);
$creditMemos->setOrder('created_at','DESC');
$creditMemos->load();

foreach ($creditMemos->getAllItems() as $item) {
   //var_dump($creditMemo->getData());
    //echo $ceditMemoGrandTotal = $creditMemo->getGrandTotal();
    echo $item->getId();
    echo $item->getSku();
    echo $item->getPrice();
}
```

Please help how to get refund items of an order.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:**

If you have order increment id then you will get the creditmemo items by following code:

```
$orderIncrementId = '200000604';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

if ($order->hasCreditmemos()) {
    foreach ($order->getCreditmemosCollection() as $creditmemo) {
        echo $creditmemo_id = $creditmemo->getId();
        $creditMemo = Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo')->load($creditmemo_id);
        foreach($creditMemo->getAllItems() as $item){
            echo $item->getId();
            echo $item->getSku();
            echo $item->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

If you have order id then you will get the creditmemo items by following code:

```
$orderId = '5';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

if ($order->hasCreditmemos()) {
    foreach ($order->getCreditmemosCollection() as $creditmemo) {
        echo $creditmemo_id = $creditmemo->getId();
        $creditMemo = Mage::getModel('sales/order_creditmemo')->load($creditmemo_id);
        foreach($creditMemo->getAllItems() as $item){
            echo $item->getId();
            echo $item->getSku();
            echo $item->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you don't want to have to specify the orer number?
What if you just want the n latest refunds by timestamp?

Or just want refunds in general